# How to know the meaning of a `EntityProperty`

Tags: entity

I don't know how to get the meaning of a certain `EntityProperty`, such as the `"Ceiling"` of `"Aircraft"`. Maybe you can press <kbd>F1</kbd> to arrive at the documentation of [`AircraftData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AircraftData.html), where that particular property is described in the **Details** section.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I want to get it **programmatically**, using a **code method**. Can this dream come true?

Furthermore, I find that a lot of `EntityProperty` of a certain `Entity` are undocumented, such as the `"Price"` of `"Element"`, which you can obtain like this:

```
EntityProperties["Element"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or the "work function":

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But what is the meaning of these `EntityProperty` entries?

---

**Update:**

The "Concept" type have a `EntityProperty` similar to my desire.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This `EntityProperty` of "Concept" can illustrate what is this entity.But my final target is know what is any `EntityProperty`.Such as the `"Format"` in type of `"Periodical"` mean what?Unfortunately the type of `Periodical` have no explanation in documentation.And not all of these `EntityProperty` is self-explanatory.

Comment: Referring to the second part of your question, it seems to me that "price" is rather self-explanatory. The work function of an element, on the other hand, is a solid state thermodynamic property of the element (see [Work Function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function)). Honestly I don't think Wolfram should attempt to document and explain the meaning of standard physical concepts: if you need the work function of an element for your calculations, then you know what it is; if not, then you can look it up in your favorite general reference source.

Comment: @MarcoB Maybe my example in this post cannot convey this request exactly.When I found some other suitable `EntityProperty`,I'll update it to show this is a very usefull demand.

Comment: From the **Background** you gave I think this question should be merged with your original, which will move your answer there.  Do you agree?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Totally agree.Just because I cannot post answer in that so I give this new post. :)

Comment: Reopened as your self-answer appears clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

## Brief description

```
EntityValue["Country", "GiniIndex", "Description"]
```

> Gini index

## Detailed definition

```
EntityValue["Country", "GiniIndex", "Definition"]
```

> The extent to which the distribution of income among individuals or
>   households within an economy deviates from a perfectly equal
>   distribution. A Lorenz curve plots the cumulative percentages of total
>   income received against the cumulative number of recipients, starting
>   with the poorest individual or household. The Gini index measures the
>   area between the Lorenz curve and a hypothetical line of absolute
>   equality, expressed as a fraction of the maximum area under the line.
>   Thus a Gini index of 0 represents perfect equality, while an index of
>   1 implies perfect inequality.

Of course,you know `GiniIndex` just by first glance,But in some obscure case,this solution will help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer.

I would not take the value of `Ceiling` given in Wolfram's curated data very seriously. At best it is a nominal number set by the aircraft's manufacturer or by a government agency. Further, for many aircraft which had long manufacturing runs, operational ceiling will vary as improvements are made during the manufacturing life cycle. For the number to be useful in a serious application, you would have to know the provenance of the information used to establish the datum given, in particular, the date on which the quoted value for operational ceiling was established, what model was used for the test, and what were the test conditions, particularly, what was the take-off weight.

Here is a specific example showing the kind of variations that can be expected. I have a monograph on the Republic P-47 Thunderbolt, a WW II US fighter. It gives the operational ceiling of the early model P-47B  as 36000 ft., while the late model P-47N achieved 42000 ft. Wolfram gives the P-47's ceiling as `Quantity[42979., "Feet"]`, which I suspect was only achieved by a late model undergoing testing and not carrying a standard battle payload.

I used

```
AircraftData["P47Thunderbolt", "Ceiling"] // N
```

to get Wolfram's value.

Comment: Thanks for your concern about this post,but maybe you misunderstand this request?

Comment: @yode. Very likely I have misunderstood. Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry I'm in struggle in English.And I have updated the post to specify it.:)