# How to know the meaning of EntityProperty of an Entity

Tags: entity

## Backgroud:

This is an exactly duplicate post [with this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112741/how-to-know-the-meaning-of-a-entityproperty).That post have colosed result I cannot post my solution.But I think this is a very meaningful question still.So I post it again.

## Question

How to know the meaning of `"GiniIndex"` in `"Country"` or some other obscure `EntityProperty`?